# GraphQL Request: Determine requested resource directly out of request

Tags: graphql, reverse-proxy, open-policy-agent

unlike REST, GraphQL has only one endpoint, usually called /graphql.
I have had good experiences with REST by outsourcing the authorisation to a separate upstream service (e.g. to a proxy like Nginx / Envoy in combination with Open Policy Agent) and using the path and the HTTP verb for the decision. For example, the GET /billing route could only be used by a user with the JWT roles claim "accountant".

Now I am looking for a way to adapt this with GraphQL.
The only possibility I have found is to interpret the query in the request body, e.g.:

```
body: {
  query: 'query {\r\n  cats {\r\n    id,\r\n    name\r\n  }\r\n}\r\n'
}
```

However, this seems to be quite complex and error-prone, as a lot of knowledge and logic would have to be outsourced, especially since the proxies (resp. OPA / other authorisation solutions) don't necessarily have any GraphQL capabilities.

Is there any better way to trustworthily identify which resolver / query / mutation / entity is being requested in a GraphQL request? Headers and other enrichments set by the client are not suitable here, right?

I would highly appreciate any appraoch!

Answer (score 1):

That does indeed look error prone. The GraphQL docs recommend moving [authorization](https://graphql.org/learn/authorization/) checks to the [business logic layer](https://graphql.org/learn/thinking-in-graphs/#business-logic-layer). Quoting their example here for completeness:

```js
// Authorization logic lives inside postRepository
var postRepository = require('postRepository');
 
var postType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: ‘Post’,
  fields: {
    body: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      resolve: (post, args, context, { rootValue }) => {
        return postRepository.getBody(context.user, post);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

So rather than trying to parse the query the authz check is done in the resolver. Some discussion on using OPA with GraphQL can be found in this [issue](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/contrib/issues/101) from the OPA contrib repo.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I also came across the issue with OPA during my research. I guess there is indeed no other choice than to solve authZ directly in the resolvers.

Too bad, I was afraid of that. The pre and outsourcing would have been much more elegant and efficient.